# Google Apps Script - Sending in Google Analytics Event with Event Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I'm currently sending in some data into Google Analytics via Google Apps Script and want to assign the event value as a variable that I'm looping through. This is the current structure of the payload that is being sent into GA. How do I send in an event value that is associated with this event?

```
var payload = {
        't': 'event',
        'ec': 'Event Category',
        'ea': 'Event Action',
        'el': 'event label'
};
```

Thanks for taking a look at this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `ev` parameter. See the [Measurement Protocol Parameter Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ev) for the full set of parameters.

```
function myFunction() {

  // A simple Page view hit.
  var payload = {
    'v': '1',
    'tid': 'UA-XXXXXX-1',
    'cid': '8675309',
    't': 'pageview',
    'dp': '/APP SCRIPT/',
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
   };

  // Sending the hit.
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect", options);

  // Your current payload.
  var payload = {
    'v': '1',
    'tid': 'UA-XXXXX-1',
    'cid': '8675309',
    't': 'event',
    'ec': 'Event Category',
    'ea': 'Event Update',
    'el': 'event label',
  };

  // Assigning the event value.
  var eventValue = '12345'
  payload.ev = eventValue;

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
   };

  // Sending the hit.
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect", options);
}
```

You can also use the [Hit Builder tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) to verify if your hits are valid.

#### Updated:

Updated the example code to a full working example, passing in the `eventValue` as a variable to the `payload` object.

Comment: Hi Matt,

Thanks for that! Unfortunately whenever I add the 'ev' parameter along with a variable for this value, my hits don't get sent into GA.

If I send in the 'ev' as a string then the hits work fine however this isn't what I want to do.

Is there anyway I can pass the 'ev' in as a variable?

Comment: @LGalliers I have updated my code to a full working appscript example passing the `ev` parameter to the payload object as a variable. If you still are unable to get it to work perhaps update your example code to show the full context of attempting to pass in the event value. Also note that it takes some time for values to update in the reports so you may not be getting the full impact of your code changes immediately. Tricks for getting the most recent (not cached) info from the reports would be to add a segment, or add a dimension.

Comment: Hi, I am struggling to get tracking going ... your example so far is the completest thing I got so far. What value do I need to paste for dp, where you put `/APP SCRIPT/`

Comment: @helle `dp` stands for [document path](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dp) which really makes sense for page views. so depending on what type of event your are sending you may or may not want to send the `document path` parameter.

Comment: I am experiencing further problems, when I don't transfer the UA, events get not tracked most of the time ... In the google appscript addon I cannot access that information ... how did you solve that?